# Is it true that I could have controls in a dialog that have command ids that overlap others in other windows?

Tags: winapi, mfc

It's been a while since I've made dynamic controls on a dialog.  If I remember correctly, dialogs are orthogonal to each other and thus, it doesn't really matter what the command ids are so long as they are different from each other ***from within*** the dialog.  It is irrelevant if they overlap any other command ids in the SDI/MDI framework.

Can someone confirm this for me?

Comment: The dialog id doesn't matter at all. It is possible to handle all operations and events with a window handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Real Question you are trying to ask

with that question you are actually asking "How does Message Map work?".  by reading your question it seems that you think that all messages go to the same place and EVERY object you have will recieve ALL those messages, but that's not true.

### How message map is created

So pratically any class derived from CWnd can have a message map (frames, dialogs, child frame, buttons, controls), so in the message map you will declare the class and the parent class that will "recieve" those messages, their ID and the method that will be called when the message is sent to the given thing

### How a message is recieved

you will need to have an object of the class you created, and this object must be already created and initialized. so then the object will be ready to recieve a message, and that message can come directly to the object using the [CWnd::SendMessage method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/t64sseb3.aspx), **or it can come from a parent CWnd object**, or it will be sent by windows via the user interface (i.e: when you click on it) but in this case Windows will have to decide which objects will actually recieve the message and to do this there are many tings taken into account (is the object active? does it need to be active to recieve the message? will it send the message to its children? does the object ignore this message? is the object out of scope? and many others...)

### Your case

many times the same ID could be used repeatedly in the same window/dialog because you might want to have two different buttons in two different places that do the same thing, for that you can create them with the same ID and when clicked they will generate the same message ID that will then be handled by the same method. If two different windows that are not related to each other (one is not the parent of the other) have a control with the same ID, when those messages are generated they will be sent to the respective window and not to the other one because "the other one" will be out of scope of that message.

Answer (score 0):

Several controls may have the same ID even on the same dialog (for example, automatically generated `IDC_STATIC` labels). It is your responsibility to provide unique IDs, if you want to do something with some control (for example, to find its `HWND` by ID).

Usually it is not a problem, if some dialog control has the same ID and another control somewhere else (for example, on another window). But if you write a code, that needs all IDs to be unique (for example, enumerate child controls of different windows and do something with IDs), you need to ensure that IDs are unique.

So, there is no general requirement for ID to be unique, unless your own code needs this.